# Redux Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm loading data from an API using Redux & React. Despite successfully pulling the data and applying it to the state, it's throwing an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'payload' of undefined.

This occurs after the `FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS_PENDING` action type in the console.

**React Component:**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import store from '../../../store';

import * as ProductListingActions from '../actions/ProductListingActions';

@connect((store) => {
    return {
        productListing: store.productListing.products
    }
})

export default class ProductListingContainer extends React.Component {
    constructor(data) {
        super();
        this.props = data;
        this.props.dispatch(ProductListingActions.fetchProductListings());
    }
    render() {
        return <div></div>;
    }
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
import CookieHandler from '../../../modules/CookieHandler';
const cookieHandler = new CookieHandler;

export default function reducer(
    state = {
        products: [],
        fetching: false,
        fetched: false,
        error: null
    }, action) {

    switch(action.type) {
        case "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS_PENDING":
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: true,
            }
            break;
        case "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS_REJECTED":
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                error: action.payload
            }
            break;
        case "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS_FULFILLED":
            return {
                ...state,
                fetching: false,
                fetched: true,
                products: action.payload.data.default
            }
            break;
    }

    return state;
}
```

**Actions:**

```
import Config from '../../../Config.js';
import store from '../../../store.js';
import axios from 'axios';

export function fetchProductListings() {
    store.dispatch({
        type: "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS",
        payload: axios.get(Config.getConfigAPIUrl() + '/cartel/products')
    })

}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're dispatching a call to dispatch, rather than dispatching an object.

```
this.props.dispatch(ProductListingActions.fetchProductListings());

function fetchProductListings() {
  store.dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS",
    payload: axios.get(Config.getConfigAPIUrl() + '/cartel/products')
  })
}
```

if you inline this:

```
this.props.dispatch(
  store.dispatch({
    type: "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS",
    payload: axios.get(Config.getConfigAPIUrl() + '/cartel/products')
  })
)
```

Your action creator should not be calling dispatch, it should just return an action:

```
export function fetchProductListings() {
  return {
    type: "FETCH_PRODUCT_LISTINGS",
    payload: axios.get(Config.getConfigAPIUrl() + '/cartel/products')
  }
}
```

Keep in mind though, `axios.get` is asynchronous, so `payload` will be promise. You may want to consider adding `redux-thunk` to handle the fulfillment of the promise.

Comment: Note - I'm already using redux-thunk, but thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I was recently using `redux-toolkit` for fetching api, and I faced the same problem. When I checked the api result, I saw my payload value was `undefined`.
I solved this problem by simply returning the result of my api data.

```
export const getPosts = createAsyncThunk("posts/getPosts", async ()=> {
  const res = await axios.get(`${baseURL}/posts/1`)
  return res.data;
});
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33409914)